# MySQL Query and Data Debugging

Tags: php, mysql

I am managing a website which has about 140.000 documents. This system had been running without a problem for more than two years using the same setup. We had to migrate our servers to a new infrastructure and since then there are some anomalies.

Every document has a status in the database. Status code (int) 5 means that the document is deleted/removed.

Every hour or so, the status code of some 10 documents changes to 5. We do not lose the actual document but it becomes unavailable to the end user. I am trying to figure out what's causing the issue, but couldn't find the source of it.

We have two queries which can change the status of the document. I have temporarily disabled one of them, and I have changed the status code of the deleted document to 6 in the codebase.

However, we still have the same problem and the status code changes to 5, not 6.

I have enabled the query log, and spent hours but there are no update queries to those deleted documents, except the view_count increase which is a very short and simple query. The document gets requested by someone at the same time it gets deleted. However, all the queries are select queries (except view_count) and there is no difference between other documents. And we have hundreds of page views every second. Only one of them gets deleted, randomly.

So, if I could see in the query log, I could try to find out that particular query in the code base. However, it even doesn't show anything. So, I am clueless right now.

Do you have any suggestions? I have to solve this issue, so I can try anything.

New system is;

Debian 6.0.5
MySQL 5.5.24 - Percona Build
PHP-NGINX-SOLR box

Comment: Did you restart MySQL after enabling the query log?

Comment: Yes I have tons of queries in the log. I just don't see any update operations related with this issue. I have investigated it a lot, so I am 100% sure it doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile `UPDATE` queries with [Jet Profiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com) or [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/), analyse them and you shall find the answer.

[General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) may also help you finding that particular update query.

Comment: Yeah, general query log didn't show anything about that as I mentioned in my post, but percona toolkit is also utilising tcpdump, so that is going to be really helpful I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Percona Toolkit is awesome, but it even didn't show anything related with this issue. (including tcpdump etc.)

I have installed Oracle build MySQL 5.5.25a, and it worked. This was the most bizarre bug I have ever seen in my whole career.